# A dot stops PHP code from functioning properly

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I use this simple code to add a basic shortcode to my Wordpress site:

```
function post_review25() { 
return '<div class="review2-5">Rating:</div>';
 }
add_shortcode('review 2.5', 'post_review25');
```

So by adding `[review 2.5]` in the visual editor, it should echo `<div class="review2-5">Rating:</div>`. However, the dot in the `review 2.5` stops it from functioning - it echo's the code for **review 2** instead (I have a shortcode set for that too).

This means that anything past the dot is not recognized. How is it possible that I can add a dot there and have it functional?

Comment: What is "add_shortcode"? It's not a standard PHP function as far as I know.

Comment: It is for adding a shortcode to Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to `add_shortcode()` should be tag-like with a few additional limitations:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

> Shortcode names should be all lowercase and use all letters, but numbers and underscores (not dashes!) should work fine too.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no possibility of using **review 2.5**? Only **review 2** works?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I wouldn't use spaces either if I were you ;-) but `review_25` should work according to the docs.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use space? It works. Is there any type of issue that I am unaware of that it would cause?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson when a document mentions `should` it roughly means that any deviation from the rule is your own responsibility

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like `[review rating="2.5"]` instead. The rating value is passed as a parameter of the handler function.

```
function post_review($atts) { 
    $rating = $atts['rating'];
    return '<div class="review'.$rating.'">Rating:</div>';
}
add_shortcode('review', 'post_review');
```

Hope that helps. :)